# добавление кода в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cms, modx, revo

постоянно добавляется этот код, не могу понять откуда, уже 100 раз удалял
cms modx revolution

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: это больше на wordpress похоже

Comment: да, но сайт на модкс рево